# Can we put authentication token in session object?

Tags: java, servlets

Can we put authentication token in session object?

For example:

```
session.setAttribute("authToken",authTokne);
```

In my case I have to use `authToken` in every request call.

In service layer i am using third party services. In each request i need to pass authentication token. Getting authentication token is also a one request. I need to do many request calls step by step. At first request i am getting token and holding it in object level. After some time i need to make another request from different location(another class/object), now token is not available here. For this one more request i need to send for token. So avoiding this every time new call for a token, Can i put this token in servlet session varaible?

In term of security reasons is it good approach?

Comment: Are you asking whether it can technically be done or whether it's a good idea?

Comment: asking is it a good idea?

Comment: why not in cookies ? is there any specific requirements

Comment: As a starting point, I suggest you check [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

The all session data is kept on the server, so you can put anything you want there.  The browser user is associated to the session via sessionId in a cookie (looked up by container upon request).  When a user connects to server, a cookie is dropped on the browser with sessionId.  Upon return the browser sends this sessionId back so you can lookup the session (usually a Map) to track data associated with the user and their current session.  Session cookies can be set to persist through browser closing or expire when browser closes or after a certain time.

Storing the auth token in session is fine, but you will not be able to find a session based on auth token stored in it if the browser doesn't support or doesn't store cookies.  If a user has no cookies (maybe a custom app that calls URLs), you would add an auth-token to the URL so that the user only logs in once per session.  In this case you would create a data store which contains session data and associate both sessionId from browser and auth token to the same data.  This is how I have done mobile/web/api session data management in the past.

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your response.